# Primefaces ajax not update UI component

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I try to apply primefaces to my project. I created a test page to demo the ajax. The listener was called but the UI component was not updated with new value.

I am using Primefaces 4.

Here is my code (I do the same with the showcase here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml):

```
<h:form id="testForm">
    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="A: #{testBean.number}" />
    <p:poll interval="30" listener="#{testBean.increment}" update="testForm:txt_count" />
    <p:ajaxStatus style="width:16px;height:16px;">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <h:panelGroup style="margin-top:5;" styleClass="statusBar">
                <h:graphicImage value="/images/ajax-busy.gif" style="width:15;height:15;margin:0;padding:0;"/> Checking... 
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="stop">
            <h:panelGroup style="margin-top:5;" styleClass="statusBar">
                <h:outputText value="&#xa0;" style="width:15;height:15;"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
    </p:ajaxStatus>
</h:form>
```

I debug on Firefox and get the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><partial-response><changes><update id="testForm:txt_count"><![CDATA[<span id="testForm:txt_count">A: 1</span>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[rO0ABXVyABNbTGphdmEubc3Npb25... too long ...weHNxAH4CcAApQ==]]></update>
```

and this error:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{2b3608be-0d4d-4533-8ca1-52b28a98a16d} Line Number
>   1, Column 56128:
>
> ...AfgG1cQB+AbVxAH4BtXBweHhweHhxAH4BpQ==]]>
>   ...-------------------------------------------------^

You can see that the response xml is missing closing tag for `<partial-response>` and `<changes>`

Could you please help me to find out the root cause?

**==============================================================================
Above issue was resolved by removing richfaces from application
==============================================================================**

**UPDATED:**
This works on Firefox but not works on IE.

Here is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq6m8.png

[image]

Comment: Is this an existing or a clean and crisp JSF project? Are you using other JSF libraries in the same webapp? E.g. RichFaces.

Comment: acctually yes, there is also richfaces in my webapp.

Comment: It's causing that trouble :/ This question is a dupe, I'm sure I've answered this before, but I can't find it right now. In any case, it's caused by a bug in RichFaces `PartialViewContext` implementation. It isn't properly delegating to wrapped instance.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for your reply. After I remove richfaces, the closing tag is back. However, the ajax still not update the component on UI. Let me see if there is any other error.

Comment: @BalusC Hi, I have updated my question and title as well. Please help to take a look. Now this works on Firefox but not on IE.